# select a next element with a specific class in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Well, I have n elements with the class "class_one"
and certain other elements with the class "class_two".

These elements are nested and in some cases there are other elements in that nest, what I need is to select the next element with a specific class.

```js
let class_one = document.querySelectorAll('.class_one');

class_one.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        console.log("From this element, the next one containing the class class_two");
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="class_one">
click 1 
</div>

<div class="class_two">elemento 1</div>

<div class="class_one">
click 2
</div>

<div class="class_four"></div>
<div class="class_two">elemento 2</div>

<div class="class_one">
click 3 
</div> 

<div class="class_six"></div>
<div class="class_two">elemento 3</div>

<div class="class_one">
click 4 
</div>

<div class="class_five">click 5</div>

<div class="class_two">elemento 4</div>

<div class="class_one">
click 6
</div>
 <div class="class_two"></div>
```

Personally, I would like an answer without using Jquery, but all are welcome.

Comment: So you need the equivalent of jQuery `$(element).next(selector)` right?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say "these elements are nested" but the html structure you provided has no nested elements.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette YES! I don't know how to use Jquery very well, but what you posted was the simplest solution, I guess I'll use Jquery instead of vanilla

Comment: Most SO users will tell you to learn vanilla JS instead, since everything jQuery can do, vanilla JS does too, and that is true.  jQuery is focussed on traversing the DOM of a quite static page. If you only need to traverse the DOM and do not care about jQuery effects and do not use Ajax, look for jQuery Slim, which is lighter.